# How do I get Postman to call a Web API

Tags: javascript, ajax, postman, webapi

I'm got the plugin Postman for Chrome. I'm just wondering how I would get Postman to call my web API.

Current, I'm using this AJAX call written in JavaScript:

```
alert("Getting security token");

// Do AJAX call to get security token:
    $.ajax({
        url: [security token url],
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json"
        },
        ContentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        data: {
            grant_type: "password",
            username: [username],
            password: [password]
        }
    }).done(function(data)
    {
        var accessToken = data.access_token;
        
        alert(accessToken);

        alert("Getting json string.");
        
        // Now that we have access token, send it along with the request for the json string:
        $.ajax({
            // meta data sent as URL parameters:
            url: [url to get json string]
            type: "GET",
            headers: {
                Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken // access token
            },
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        }).done(function(data)
        {
            $("#jsonDiv").html(data);
        }).fail(function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert("jqXhr = " + JSON.stringify(jqXhr));
            alert("textStatus = " + textStatus + ", errorThrown = " + errorThrown);
        });     
    }).fail(function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        alert("jqXhr = " + JSON.stringify(jqXhr));
        alert("textStatus = " + textStatus + ", errorThrown = " + errorThrown);
    });
```

What would I have to do in Postman to accomplish the equivalent of this?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to achieve this, but here are some steps to get you started. Create two 2 APIs:

The first to call the "security token url" with the POST method.
Add the header:

- Accept: application/json

Then under body, select x-www-form-urlencoded and then add the following keys (and their appropriate values):

- grant_type : password
- username :
- password :

Off the top of my head I think the password grant_type also requires client_id and client_secret, but I don't see that in your code above so maybe you don't need it.

If you hit send you should get an access token back.

In your second API, set the method to GET and supply the appropriate URL. Then in the headers add:
 - Authorization : Bearer

If you want to get fancy you can use the test tab to write the access token to an environment variable and then use the result in your second call.
You don't need to get a new access token for each call however so you can just keep using the same token until it expires.

Sorry if you already knew how to do this, I couldn't tell your level of expertise from your question. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is what I've been doing, but when I do my second API call, I get back: "Authorization has been denied for this request." It's weird because the Javascript I posted doesn't have this problem.

Comment: Have you tried using an access token retrieved in your Ajax code in the call to the API from postman? What happens when you do that?

Comment: Yes, I use my access token. I get the message "Authorization has been denied for this request."

Comment: If you are using the token from the Ajax call in your second API call then it suggests your second API call is incorrect. At this point I would suggest contacting the API owner to ask them what information they expect.